# USGS Tree Canopy data download issue

Tags: data, land-cover, download, usgs

I'm trying to download the **USGS NLCD 2011 Tree Canopy** data from the National Land Cover Database (http://www.mrlc.gov/nlcd11_data.php), but it's really slow. Does anyone know of an alternative site to get this data, or if it is just me that is finding it slow?

It's a 3GB file and will take 4 days at the current speed. I've been checking the website frequently for the last three days and it seems to be consistently slow. Problem is, I want the 10GB file too. I emailed them about it and they said to reset my browser, but then never replied to subsequent emails after that. I download GIS data all the time from different sources, so I don't think the issue is on my end.

Comment: I started a download and was getting speeds of about 40 KB/s. Here is a WMS link, which might be faster... [NationalMap](https://raster.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/LandCover/USGS_EROS_LandCover_NLCD/MapServer)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't deal specifically with GIS software or data, but rather web connectivity and/or hosting issues

Comment: @HDunn since we allow questions looking for data sets, I'm inclined to allow this one since it's asking for alternative sources.

Comment: I've had this same issue. I think it actually has to do with the server they have the data on rather than your connection.

Answer (score 3):

The data can also be downloaded for the National Map (as part of the 2011 NLCD dataset), but it's in 3x3 degree segments so there are 131 parts to download. They can all be downloaded at once if you use the Download Manager. Multiple people find the download from the USGS NLCD website slow, so it's probably an issue with their server.